# How to check string on it has mixed letters in one word?

Tags: php

How to check string on it has mixed (latin & cyrillic) symbols in one word?
For example:

```
$str = 'This is test string'; //ok
$str = 'This is тест string'; //ok
$str = 'This is тестstring'; // <-- fail, how to detect this?
```

More examples:

```
$str = 'This is тест_123 string'; //ok
$str = 'This is {тест}_string'; //fail
$str = 'Абвгabcd'; //fail
$str = 'Абвг_abcd'; //fail
$str = 'Абвг abcd'; //ok
$str = 'This sentence has русское word'; //ok
$str = 'This has splittedкириллицаletters word'; //fail
```

Comment: and what attempts have you made?

Comment: And why is `тест_123` ok?

Comment: And why would `тест string` and not `тестstring` pass? That sounds more like some kind of custom (and seemingly random) spelling check than a character check, since they contain the exact same characters, minus an extra space.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `тест_123` is ok because in this case symbols is not mixed (latin & cyrillic), has only cyrillic, numbers and specials

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i added more examples

Comment: We don't need more examples, we need an _explanation_. We have _no idea_ what your rules are. They seem pretty random. (I'm sure there's some logic to it, but it's anything but obvious).

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale im tried some regexp `/\s[a-zA-Z]/g` but no luck, it too hard for me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson logic is very simple, i just need to detect when string contains word (or many words) consisted from latin characters and any foreign alphabet characters (cyrillic). If words separated by space its ok, but if it separated by some special character like `{` or `_` its not.

Comment: That explanation doesn't fit with your examples. How would `This is тест string` be OK and not `This is тестstring`? The only difference is that there's an extra space in the first. How does your explanation cover that? And if `_` isn't allowed, why would `тест_123` be OK?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `тестstring` this word mixed from cyrillic & latin. Yes `_` not allowed, but `тест_123` not contains latin characters, only cyrillic, numbers and specials.

Comment: I can help you with the explenation. If a word (between two `\b` in regex) has a mix of cyrillic and latin letters it's a fail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution, it passed all tests

```
$result = preg_match_all('/\S*[а-яА-Я]\S*[a-zA-Z]\S*|\S*[a-zA-Z]\S*[а-яА-Я]\S*/', $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return `0` for no matches and `1` for a match.  You need to add any special characters that are not allowed into `[a-z]`, such as `[a-z}{]`:

```
$result = preg_match('/([a-z]\p{Cyrillic})|(\p{Cyrillic}[a-z])/iu', $str, $matches);
```

To get the words pass `$matches` as the third parameter and it will be populated with the matches.  To get more than one match:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]\p{Cyrillic})|(\p{Cyrillic}[a-z])/iu', $str, $matches);
```

To do the opposite and find the good words:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]\s+\p{Cyrillic})|(\p{Cyrillic}\s+[a-z])/iu', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Edited if I understand.